# How to generate a list of cycles from a list of edges?

Tags: python, tuples, graph-theory

I have a list of edges in a fully connected graph where each edge is represented as a tuple of the two nodes it connects. I want to enumerate all possible simple cycles in the graph.

Example with a 3-node graph:
Given:

`[(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1)]`

Want to generate:

```
[
     [(0,1),(1,0)],
     [(0,2),(2,0)],
     [(1,2),(2,1)],
     [(0,1),(1,2),(2,0)],
     [(0,2),(2,1),(1,0)]
 ]
```

Not that the order of the edges in the cycle doesn't matter i.e.
[(0,1),(1,0)] and  [(1,0),(0,1)] denote the same cycle.

I tried to use itertools to generate the cycles and was not successful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might want to check out NetworkX package:

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles

Comment: You have missed the (non-simple) cycles `(0,1),(1,2),(2,1),(1,0)` and `(0,2),(2,1),(1,2),(2,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is a modified depth first search. When a previously visited vertex is reached, the Dijkstra algorithm is applied to find if there is a path that forms the shortest cycle that leads around and back.

Sounds straight forward, but there a number of gotcha's

- Directed graphs are easier than undirected, which require extra checks to prevent false cycles going back and and forth on the same edge
- A cycle can be found several times starting at different vertices.  It is necessary to check that each cycle is novel, not a repeat. ( I notice that in your example you include the 0-1-2 cycle twice, going in opposite directions.  If that is really what you want, then you can ignore this point)
- Do you want to handle graphs with more than one component?  If so, the DFS needs to be restarted at unvisited vertices, until all vertices have been visited.

For reference, here is some C++ code that implements this: https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/412c81b79d9f1a9cc91b61293050f93c51522ab1/src/GraphTheory.cpp#L310-L429  You might want to port this to Python, but I wouldn't recommend it - on graphs with a significant number of nodes Python is going to be awfully slow.

Comment: I'm only interested in graphs that are fully connected. So for a given cycle involving n nodes, starting out with any of them as my root node should return the same cycle. And yes, I do care about the direction of the cycle so you will see both the clockwise and anticlockwise directions for a given cycle. Given that the graph is always going to be fully connected, do I still need a dfs algorithm?

Comment: The modified DFS algorithm described in the first paragraph is necessary.  A further modification is required to handle graphs with multiple components.

Comment: Where is your input coming from?  How can you be certain that every input will be fully connected ( i.e. every node is reachable from every other node )

Comment: I have refactored the code to to clarify the handling of graphs that are not fully connected and added a unit test for a simple graph that is not fully connected.  Test code https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/412c81b79d9f1a9cc91b61293050f93c51522ab1/src/test.cpp#L110-L127

Comment: My objective is to enumerate all possible cycles. Not to find cycles for a given input. As such, one can assume that the graph is fully connected which essentially translates to having the maximum number of cycles possible.

Comment: Your question title is "How to generate a list of cycles from a list of edges?"  Where does this list of edges come from?  How do you know that this list includes edges that connect every vertex to every other vertex?